# Share Folders on OpenSUSE 13.1 Using SAMBA (Share Not Working)?

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba, opensuse

Gentlemen,

I tried all ways to share folders on OpenSUSE 13.1 using SAMBA, but without success. Frankly, I do not know what to do to resolve this situation.

Among my actions are taken...

1. Stop the firewall
2. Do the procedures set out in :

   - http://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-samba-server-on-opensuse-13-1/
   - http://www.howtoforge.com/opensuse-12.3-samba-standalone-server-with-tdbsam-backend
   - http://opensuse-guide.org/windows.php (under "12.2.2 Sharing Your Files")
   - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated%2C%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way%21 (a tutorial that I made)

I can make the server work normally and without error including its parameters (testparm), but I can not access it from another machine (Linux or Windows) using "smb://[MACHINE_IP]/[SHARE_NAME]" or "\[MACHINE_IP][SHARE_NAME]"! I also tested using the machine itself.

Nothing seems to make samba work. What was supposed to be a simple and ordinary thing in other distributions became a nightmare. I'm beginning to think that this is a problem in the distribution itself!

I can not imagine what can be done! = /

Please help me!

Thanks in advance!

**More!**

Below I put the outputs of the smbd and nmbd logs!

These logs covering the time when I start the service to when I try to access the share from another computer!

vim /var/log/samba/log.smbd

```
[2014/02/10 11:58:31,  0] ../source3/smbd/server.c:1198(main)
  smbd version 4.1.3-3.12.1-3127-SUSE-oS13.1-x86_64 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2013
[2014/02/10 11:58:31.412297,  0] ../source3/smbd/server.c:1278(main)
  standard input is not a socket, assuming -D option
```

vim /var/log/samba/log.nmbd

```
[2014/02/10 11:58:26,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd.c:902(main)
  nmbd version 4.1.3-3.12.1-3127-SUSE-oS13.1-x86_64 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2013
[2014/02/10 11:58:26,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd.c:941(main)
  standard input is not a socket, assuming -D option
```

**"iptables --list" RESULT:**

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED
input_ext  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-IN-ILL-TARGET "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-FWD-ILL-ROUTING "

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain forward_ext (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain input_ext (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = broadcast udp dpt:netbios-ns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = broadcast udp dpt:netbios-dgm
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = broadcast
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:netbios-ns ctstate RELATED
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp dpt:netbios-ssn flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP "
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp dpt:microsoft-ds flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP "
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = multicast
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = broadcast
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT "
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT "
LOG        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 ctstate NEW LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain reject_func (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with tcp-reset
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
```

**Conclusions so far:**

Some peculiarity of the corporate network where I work is blocking access to Samba OpenSUSE 13.1, because in my home network samba works perfectly.

The OpenSUSE 13.1 is running on a VMWare using NAT network. In my view there should not be any interference from the outside network, since I'm using NAT.

I have an other virtual machine running Linux Mint 16 KDE on VMWare using NAT. Samba works perfectly in both my home network and the corporate network which leads me to believe that this is some configuration to be taken in the openSUSE 13.1 to make samba work.

Below I put the output from running "smbclient" over my host to both virtual machines:

```
smbclient //172.16.124.141/share -N -U'brlight%brlight'
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.18]
smb: \>

smbclient //172.16.124.136/share -N -U'brlight%brlight'
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT
```

**This link has detailed and additional information about my problem.**

https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/495277-Share-Folders-on-OpenSUSE-13-1-Using-SAMBA-(Share-Not-Working)

Comment: are the services running?  **rcnmb status** and **rcsmb status**  both should saying **running** on the right hand side.

Comment: next samba generates a lot of helpful logging.  check **cat /var/log/samba/log.nmbd** and **cat /var/log/samba/log.smbd**

Comment: I use samba on  OpenSuSE all the time BTW

Comment: cybernard, 

The commands that worked to inform status were: 

"/bin/systemctl status smb.service" and "/bin/systemctl status nmb.service"

I added up the outputs of the logs for you to take a look!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gentlemen,

The solution to the problem is change the hypervisor. In my case at least... I switched to VirtualBox (was using VMWare). 
The trick is create two network interfaces: one NAT and one "host only". 
NAT allows the guest to access the internet and "host only" allows host access to the guest there **including the samba share**. 
As I said, in my case, this problem is related to the corporate network I was using. 
It is possible that the same procedure works for VMWare (not tested).

More information about the procedure: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jk5Kfm2-Muk

Thanks Matt Fuller!

**[EDIT I]**

I used the same procedure on VMWare Workstation, ie add a network adapter with a "host only" network and other with a "NAT" network, but the behavior was the same: "no samba"!

**[EDIT II]**

Access samba's share using the interface "host only". Use the "ifconfig" command to help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        printcap cache time = 750
        cups options = raw
        map to guest = Bad User
        include = /etc/samba/dhcp.conf
        logon path = \\%L\profiles\.msprofile
        logon home = \\%L\%U\.9xprofile
        logon drive = P:
        usershare allow guests = Yes

[sharename]
        comment = Stuff
        valid users = root, %S, %D%w%S
        path=<location of files>
        read only = No
```

is the output of
**iptables --list**
This:

- Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
  destination

  Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
  destination

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
  destination

Comment: I added up more information about the problem and the information that you requested.

Comment: Using the command "rcSuSEfirewall2 stop" I get the output you mentioned. But I'm still having the same problems!

Comment: next up.  **rcapparmor stop**  Try again.  Rename your /etc/samba/smb.conf file and make a new one with mine above. Then restart the services.  **rcnmb restart** and **rcsmb restart**  Try again

Comment: Make sure to substitute a valid path for **location of files**

Comment: I tested the above procedures, but got the same result. As I explain in https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/495277-Share-Folders-on-OpenSUSE-13-1-Using-SAMBA-(Share-Not-Working)/page3 link the issue is in some samba's configuration (to ignore the external network, i believe). Although the host is configured for NAT, plugs it into the "external" network because a side effect in OpenSUSE's samba (NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT).

Comment: I believe also that has no relation to the "range" of IP host, otherwise it would have the same problem on my home network. Note also that the samba client "sees" the OpenSUSE's samba service because if I limit interfaces in global parameters ("interfaces = ..." and "bind interfaces only = yes"), I get an "NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error. If I set a range that "allowing connection" like "interfaces = 172.16.124." the error is again "NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT". This is a really difficult problem to solve =\.

Comment: If you use NAT you need to forward the necessary ports.  If your samba box is on 192.168.1.1 (for example) and outside the VM your network is 1.1.1.1 without port forwarding traffic will hit 1.1.1.1 and die.